# Scala: assigning class properties with alternate constructors

Tags: scala, class, constructor

I have a class with a property that is populated by the constructor, but I need it to be populated in a different way when the alternate constructor is called. E.g. I want the code to be something like this:

```
class MyClass(someArg: String) {
  val someValue = valuePopulator(someArg)

  def this(someArg1: String, someArg2: String) {
    someValue = alternateValuePopulator(someArg1, someArg2)
  }
  def valuePopulator(arg: String) {
  \\ does something
  }
  def alternateValuePopulator(arg: String, arg2: String) {
  \\ does something else
  }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work, but basically I want `someValue` to equal the output of `valuePopulator` when the class is constructed normally. However, `someValue` should be the result of `alternateValuePopulator` when the alternate constructor is called. How can I create class properties that are populated by the constructor in a way that depends on which constructor is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common denominator between the two constructors seems to be a primary constructor that accepts `someValue` directly:

```
class MyClass private (val someValue: SomeValueType) {

  def this(someArg: String) {
    this(valuePopulator(someArg))
  }

  def this(someArg1: String, someArg2: String): SomeValueType = {
    this(alternateValuePopulator(someArg1, someArg2))
  }

  def valuePopulator(arg: String) {
  \\ does something
  }
  def alternateValuePopulator(arg: String, arg2: String): SomeValueType = {
  \\ does something else
  }
}
```